Renaming string via key/value matrix
I am attempting to rename strings that have been pulled from a user-defined field. So, I have set up a matrix that creates a relationship between what comes from the UDF and what I want that string to be renamed as.
Here is pseudo example of my matrix (CSV):
Key,Value
FooBar1234,Test 1
ASDF[1234]=qwerty,Test 2
Yellow,Test 3
YellowString,Test 3
1234567890,Test 1
Foo,Test 1
Jane Smith,Test 4
Jane,Test 4
Jane(ABC),Test 4

Here is an example of the data that my script is getting fed (CSV):
FooBar1234
ASDF[1234]=qwerty
Yellow
YellowString
1234567890
Foo
Jane Smith
Jane
Jane(ABC)
Jane(abc)

Here is my PowerShell script:
$path = 'Path\To\CSV\file.csv'

$data = Import-Csv $path -Header UDFName

$matrix = @{}
#import matrix
$re = Import-Csv 'Path\To\Matrix\file.csv' | ForEach-Object{
    #key equals value
    $matrix[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    [regex]::Escape($_.Key)
}
$re = $re -join '|' -as [regex]


$data | ForEach-Object {

    $udf_rename = $re.Replace($_.UDFName,  { $matrix[$args[0].Value] })

    $_.UDFName = $udf_rename

    $_

}| ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Set-Content $path

And this is the full output:
"Test 1"
"Test 2"
"Test 3"
"Test 3String"
"Test 1"
"Test 1"
"Test 4"
"Test 4"
"Test 4(ABC)"
"Test 4(abc)"

The issue that I'm running into (aside from the fact that it's a user-defined field ) is that when I try to replace the Key with the Value, my code only replaces part of the input string for some inputs. For example, if YellowString is passed through the loop, I would anticipate to see Test 3 as the result. However, because Yellow,Test 3 is part of the matrix, I end up getting Test 3String as the result. My loop only replaces the Yellow portion of YellowString because of the relationship that's set up between Yellow and Test 3 in the matrix. Something similar happens with Jane and Jane(ABC).
Unfortunately, I cannot remove Yellow,Test 3 and the other variations from the matrix, so I need to figure out how to exactly match the input string. I tried stripping all the spaces from the Keys, but it still yields the same result. I also thought that maybe I could attach unique codes to each key and then translate that way, but then I run into the same problem when it comes to replacement. Any ideas? Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Your match should happen from left to right, so YellowString when matched against Yellow|YellowString will match on Yellow but when matched against YellowString|Yellow will match on YellowString. Sort your regex patterns longest to shortest before joining them with pipes. $re = ($re | sort length -descending) -join '|' -as [regex]

Is there a way to make this non-case sensitive? I'm hoping that Jane(ABC), Test 4 can replace Jane(abc) and Jane(ABC).


PowerShell's regex functionality and .NET's regex APIs operate on substrings by default.
(E.g., 'food' -replace 'oo', '@@' yields 'f@@d', as does ([regex] 'oo').Replace('food', '@@'))
To ensure that each input string is matched in full, anchor each regex with ^...$:
'^{0}$' -f [regex]::Escape($_.Key)

Note: The above uses -f, the format operator to synthesize the string; alternatively, use
'^' + [regex]::Escape($_.Key) + '$' or
"^$([regex]::Escape($_.Key))`$"

I considered this, but I wasn't sure that the phrase to replace will be the only thing on the line. If so, this is the best answer

For simplicity sake, I failed to mention that the data that I feed the script looks more like this (one line, for example): A123,FooBar1234,0000,123456789 ... and so on. I'm assuming this regex you posted targets the beginning of the line, which is why when I paste it in, it doesn't work as intended. Apologies for not being clearer about the data, initially.

@Crimp: You're performing the replacement on one property of your parsed-into-objects CSV data ($_.UDFName), so there's no concern about about matching on a whole line.

Thanks, @DougMaurer; please see the comment I just addressed to Crimp.

I think this is what I'm looking for! At a quick glance when applied to my larger group of data, everything seems to have correctly been renamed. The only outliers are other weird string variations that are not found in my original matrix. Thank you sir!

Is there a way to make this non-case sensitive? For example, if YellowString is fed through the script and yellowstring is in the matrix, the loop won't pick it up and rename it

Glad to hear it, @Crimp. The simplest way to make your regex case-insensitive is to prepend an inline option to the regex string: '(?i)', i.e. $re = '(?i)' + ($re -join '|') -as [regex]. Note that PowerShell's operators are generally case-insensitive by default (and have case-sensitive variants, e.g. -creplace), and in PowerShell (Core) 7 you could use a -replace operation instead: $udf_rename = $_.UDFName -replace $re, { $matrix[$_.Value] } (you could then leave $re as a string).

A simple non-regex approach is:
$data | foreach-object {
    $matrix.ContainsKey($_) ? $matrix[$_] : $_
}

which outputs
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 3
Test 1
Test 1
Test 4
Test 4
Test 4
Test 4

This uses the PowerShell Ternary operator (<condition> ? <if-true> : <if-false>) (which is not available in Windows PowerShell 5.1) to basically say if the data string matches a key in the lookup matrix then return the value for that key, otherwise just return the data string verbatim.
If you need it to work in Windows PowerShell 5.1 you can use the slightly longer form:
$data | foreach-object {
    if( $matrix.ContainsKey($_) ) { $matrix[$_] } else { $_ }
}


Set a word boundary on your regex with \b...\b
$path = 'Path\To\CSV\file.csv'

$data = Import-Csv $path -Header UDFName

$matrix = @{}
#import matrix
$re = Import-Csv 'Path\To\Matrix\file.csv' | ForEach-Object{
    #key equals value
    $matrix[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    '\b{0}\b' -f [regex]::Escape($_.Key)
}
$re = $re -join '|' -as [regex]


$data | ForEach-Object {

    $udf_rename = $re.Replace($_.UDFName,  { $matrix[$args[0].Value] })

    $_.UDFName = $udf_rename

    $_

}| ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Set-Content $path

Output
udfname
-------
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 3
Test 1
Test 1
Test 4
Test 4
Test 4(ABC)
Test 4(abc)

That handles the yellowstring.
EDIT
If you add the lower case (abc) to your matrix, use the suggestion by @TheMadTechnician, and use the initial \b - then this works
$re = $csv | ForEach-Object{
    #key equals value
    $matrix[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    '\b{0}' -f [regex]::Escape($_.Key)
}

$re = ($re | sort length -descending) -join '|'

$data | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.udfname -match $re){
        $_.UDFName -replace  [regex]::escape($matches[0]),$matrix[$matches[0]]
    }
}

Output
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 3
Test 1
Test 1
Test 4
Test 4
Test 4
Test 4

To update the property just assign it back to $_.udfname
$data | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.udfname -match $re){
        $_.UDFName = $_.UDFName -replace  [regex]::escape($matches[0]),$matrix[$matches[0]]
    }
}


Is there a way to handle Jane(ABC) and Jane(abc)? In my matrix I have Jane(ABC),Test 4, but with this solution it doesn't seem to handle that. Additionally, I failed to mention that I would like to disregard case. I'm hoping that a relation of Jane(ABC),Test 4 will be able to replace Jane(ABC) and Jane(abc) alike.
